# MIgration didn't work rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I have an attribute in `tasks` table, it's named `is_active` and it is `boolean`.But I've forgot to set the default value to this attribute when I was creating a table.So now I'm trying to set this value to `true` by default,but as I can see from sqlite browser - new tasks are still creating with this value set to `NULL`.Can you please help me to find where is the problem in my migration?

Migration file:

```
class AddDefaultValueToTask < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    def up
      change_column :tasks, :is_active, :boolean, :default =>  true
    end

    def down
      change_column :tasks, :is_active, :boolean, :default =>  nil
    end
  end
end
```

Schema.rb file

```
create_table "tasks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "body"
    t.boolean  "is_active"
    t.integer  "project_id"
    t.string   "deadline"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["project_id"], name: "index_tasks_on_project_id"
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the hash rocket operator: '`=>`'

```
change_column :tasks, :is_active, :boolean, :default => true
```

Also, if you are using `up` and `down` then you need to delete the `change` block.  Both methods cannot be used at the same time

Comment: reversed the migration,added hashrocket, still  no changes

Comment: try taking out the `def change` block, and just leave the `up` and `down` blocks.  See if that helps